# Como solucionar Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_array()

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

estoy intentendo hacer una tabla que muestre los datos de la tabla mascotas por medio de un arreglo, se espera que se muestren todos los campos de la tabla mascotas, pero solo aparece un error **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_array() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Crud-Mascotas-Ajax\CRUD.php:43 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Crud-Mascotas-Ajax\CRUD.php on line 43**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CRUD Mascotas</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
</head>
<body>

   <div align="center" class="starter-template">
       <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"> 
   </span>Nuevo
       </button> 
   </div>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-heading">Lista de mascotas</div>
       <table class="table">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>ID Mascota</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Fecha De Nacimiento</th>
                <th>Raza</th>
                <th>Especie</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
               <?php 

                    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","crud-ajax");
                    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM MASCOTA"); 
               while($filas=mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
               { ?> 

          <tr>
             <td><?php echo $filas['idmascota']; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $filas['nombre']; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $filas['fechanacimiento']; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $filas['raza']; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $filas['especie']; ?></td>
             <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Seleccione</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                      <li><a>Eliminar</a></li>
                      <li><a>Actualizar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
             </td>
          </tr>
           <?php    
           }
           ?>   



       </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: Busca en el sitio. Esta pregunta ya se ha hecho y tiene respuesta: estás usando una versión de PHP que no tiene las funciones mysql_* (que se consideran obsoletas desde PHP 5 y fueron eliminadas en PHP 7).

Comment: Aparte de que estás mezclando funciones `mysql_*` con `mysqli_*` (en cuyo caso el problema podría ser un fallo tipográfico al faltarte una `i` en el nombre de la función).

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, tienes razon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En lugar de usar mysql_fetch_array, intenta usar mysqli_fetch_array